# Simple MySQL Login - Help Needed

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a login system in place with a remote mysql server for a website.

I have the system below which works fine:

```
mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
        mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=server.com; userid=nathand2_portico; password=password; database=nathan_database"
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        mydbcon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM info WHERE username = '{0}' AND password = '{1}'", Me.Username.Text.Trim(), Me.Password.Text.Trim())
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
        reader = Command.ExecuteReader

        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While reader.Read
            count = count + 1

        End While

        If count = 1 Then
            Panel2.Visible = True
            Panel2.BringToFront()
            Timer1.Start()
```

But, whilst the above works fine - I want to add another part in. In my database, I have a field called 'active' and only want them to be able to login if the field 'active' equals 1.

But, I don't know how to do it. Can you please help me?

Comment: Never, ever store passwords as plaintext.  Hash and salt them.

Comment: Plutonix - Hi, how do I do that? I'm new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just update your query

SELECT * FROM info WHERE username = '{0}' AND password = '{1}' and active =1

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query building statement to be like below. Again you don't need `'` around the placeholders in `string.Format()` method.

```
    Query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM info WHERE username = {0} AND password = {1} AND active = 1", Me.Username.Text.Trim(), Me.Password.Text.Trim())
```

Moreover, you are just trying to check whether the user is an existing user or not and in such case can change your query to be

```
   Query = String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM info WHERE username = {0} AND password = {1} AND active = 1", Me.Username.Text.Trim(), Me.Password.Text.Trim())
```

And use `ExecuteScalar()` method instead of `ExecuteReader()`